# DOJO custom build for DOJOX Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo-build

I tried to create a dojo custom build for DOJO (version 1.9.3) with the following profile.

```
var profile = (function() {
return {
    releaseDir: "../release",
    basePath: "../../",
    action: "release",
    mini: true,
    selectorEngine: "lite",
    layerOptimize: "closure",
    cssOptimize: "comments",

    packages:[{
        name: "dojo",
        location: "dojo"
    },{
        name: "dijit",
        location: "dijit"
    },{
        name: "dojox",
        location: "dojox"
    }],

     layers: {
        "dojo/dojo": {
            includeLocales: ["en-gb","en-us"],
            include: [ 
                        "dojox/gantt/GanttTaskControl",
                        "dojox/gantt/GanttChart",
                        "dojox/gantt/GanttProjectItem",
                        "dojox/gantt/GanttResourceItem",
                        "dojox/gantt/GanttProjectControl",
                        "dojox/gantt/TabMenu"             
            ], 
            boot: true
        }
    },

    defaultConfig: {
        hasCache:{
            "dojo-built": 1,
            "dojo-loader": 1,
            "dom": 1,
            "host-browser": 1,
            "host-node": 0,
            "config-selectorEngine": "lite"
        },
        async: 1
    },

    staticHasFeatures: {
        "config-dojo-loader-catches": 0,
        "config-tlmSiblingOfDojo": 0,
        "dojo-log-api": 0,
        "dojo-sync-loader": 0,
        "dojo-timeout-api": 0,
        "dojo-sniff": 0,
        "dojo-cdn": 0,
        "config-strip-strict": 0,
        "dojo-loader-eval-hint-url": 1,
        "dojo-firebug": 0,
        "dojo-debug-messages": 0
    }
};
})();
```

It is created the dojo.js file successfully in the release folder, but when I try to create an  instance for `GanttChart` it is failing with the following error message.

> Cannot read property 'GanttChart' of undefined.

While debugging I found, dojox does not have any properties or methods init.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Thanks a lot.